# $p(n)/\log p(n)={}$prime

Tags: prime-numbers

A little item for anyone who wants to test their new exaflop machine.  Given some $\operatorname{prime}(n)/\log\operatorname{prime}(n)={}$as near as possible to a prime $q,$ for both log base $10$ and base $e,$ what is $\operatorname{prime}(n)$?  Near as possible means the minimum difference from either above or below $q;$ thus $126.9999$ or $127.00001$ would be considered to be very close to prime $127.$

Comment: So $prime(n)$ is the $n$'th prime number ?

Comment: Yes, p(n) is the nth prime.

Comment: Using Wolfram Alpha over the Internet (which is quite likely nowhere near exaflop) I get 1, 3, 5, 9, 16, 23, 28, 29, ... `Select[Range[1000], PrimeQ[Round[Prime[#]/Log[Prime[#]]]] && PrimeQ[Round[Prime[#]/Log[10, Prime[#]]]] &]`

Comment: The point is to find the particular prime(n) which produces AS CLOSE AS possible that prime q and print what q is.  It is NOT the same as simply rounding q.

Comment: Prime(29)=109, divided by log base 10  gives 53.49877, which is not very close to  pure 53; divided by log base e gives 23.234, which is also not very close to pure 23.  Very close means a few thousandths or less.